# Making subplots in Dash for Julia

Tags: plotly, julia, plotly-dash, subplot, plots.jl

In Plotly for python there's the useful method "make_subplots" to make nice subplots; is there anything similar in plotly for julia? Alternatively, is it possible to use plots.jl to make plotls in Dash for julia?

What I'm trying to make here is a dashboard with a grid of plots with a variable number or rows and columns, depending on the data to show and user's settings. I'd like to do it with subplots, but from what I understood the only way to do this is plotly for julia is to pass a list of traces to the data to plot. But is it possible to add traces to subplots defined this way? It is also quite hard to do it iteratively, with variable rows and columns number.

Thank you, any help is appreciated!